# I am trying to make a stick figure in java

Tags: java

I got the head, one arm and the body. I am trying to make another arm using the same first two coordinates, which starts at the bottom of the head, but a negative last (but same number) last two coordinates. I assumed that if I made a negative version, it would just make an opposite version of the line. Instead, its just sticking straight up! I am confused on why this is happening.

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class StickFigure extends JComponent
{
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
 {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    Ellipse2D.Double head = new Ellipse2D.Double(5, 10, 50, 50);
    g2.draw(head);

    Line2D.Double body=new Line2D.Double(30,60, 30,150);
    g2.draw(body);

    Line2D.Double arm1=new Line2D.Double(30,60,75,75);
    g2.draw(arm1);
    Line2D.Double arm2=new Line2D.Double(30,60,-75,-75);
    g2.draw(arm2);

    }
}
```

That is the code that is giving me trouble. I am using a viewer which is the following:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Viewer
{
public static void main(String[] arg)
{
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(1000,500);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    StickFigure fig1=new StickFigure();
    frame.add(fig1);
    frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Try     Line2D.Double arm2=new Line2D.Double(30,60,0,45);

Comment: This one is the closest! thank you, I am going to try and bring the arm down. I see what coordinate needs to move. thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
Line2D.Double arm2=new Line2D.Double(30,60,-75,-75);
```

You need to think about what you're saying with -75 and -75. Remember those make a coordinate, and (0, 0) represents the top left corner in Swing (unless you're explicitly telling it not to). Those coordinates are offscreen to the northwest.

Try something like:

```
Line2D.Double arm2=new Line2D.Double(30,60, 45,75);
```

Comment: As you can see,I have no idea what I am doing with Java haha. I used your coordinates and the arms are on the same side now. I see what you are saying though.

Comment: Sorry yeah i kind of guessed on the coordinates -- just fiddle with it until it looks good :p

Answer (score 0):

Try using a positive y last coordinate for both:

```
Line2D.Double arm1=new Line2D.Double(30,60,75,75);
g2.draw(arm1);
Line2D.Double arm2=new Line2D.Double(30,60,-75,75);
g2.draw(arm2);
```

You are right that -75 -75 "would just make an opposite version of the line", but when you alter both coordinates you get *radial* simmetry, that is simmetry around a point (the neck) hence one of your arm is low and the other is up. You want *axial* symmetry in this case, and for that you only need to flip one coordinate; since people's axis of symmetry is the spine, and it is vertical (*y*-direction) you need to flip coordinate *x* only.

Comment: I think  I get what you are saying, I am trying to flip the coordinates around now, but its just two arms on the same side. I feel that I am missing something, or messing something up...